# Removing/Subtracting Lead Resistance Using Op Amp Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, resistance, operational-amplifier, rtd

I'm working with RTD sensor, and need to use Op Amp circuitry.

Can someone explain to me how this Op Amp circuit work to remove the lead resistance?

So that Rw1, Rw2, and Rw3 vanish, hence the output from Op Amp Vout3 = IREFF * RTD
[image]

along with the calculation please if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just give an intuitive answer with some numbers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1T2lJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The circuit redrawn.*

- We'll leave out R<sub>W2</sub> and R7 for now since there is no significant current flowing to the + input.
- With 1 mA flowing through the RTD the voltages are as shown in Figure 1. Note that the bottom of the RTD is at 2 mV and the top at 102 mV.
- The + input is also at 102 mV.
- The right side of RW1 is at 104 mV.
- The op-amp is in an inverting mode configuration. That means that the output will move to that value that makes the - input equal to the + input (102 mV). Since the amplifier input is 104 mV and 2 mV is dropped across R5 another 2 mV will be dropped across R6 since both R5 and R6 are the same value.
- The result is that the output is 100 mV which is the correct value for 1 mA through 100 Ω.

R7 is included to remove any errors due to op-amp bias currents. The - input bias current is feeding into two 100k resistors so a value of half of 100k is used on the + input. The missing 0.1 Ω  is presumably to allow for RW2.

Comment: Actually 49.9 ohms is a standard resistor value, 50 ohm values are used in RF systems and are often oddball wattage, sizes and usually cost >> than an E96 scale part.

Comment: `@isdi: Thanks. I haven't memorized beyond E12! I didn't know that.